# Getting org.testng.TestNGException: No free nodes found in:[DynamicGraph Exception

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to write same class more than once in my testng.xml.
for e.g i have two methods `login()` and `logout()` in `Login` class.

First i want to execute Login class's `login()` method then OtherClass's `method()` and finally Login class's `logout()` method

```
<test name="scenario1">
   <classes>
      <class name="com.webaut.Login">
          <methods>
             <include name="login" />
           </methods>
       </class>

      <class name="com.webaut.OtherClass">
          <methods>
             <include name="method" />
           </methods>
       </class>


       <class name="com.webaut.Login">
           <methods>
              <include name="logout" />
           </methods>
       </class> 
   </classes>
</test>
```

After executing my suit i get an "org.testng.TestNGException:  No free nodes found in:[DynamicGraph Exception"

I could have used `@DataProvider`, but my methods are different so please suggest any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that each class can only be declared once in the  list, even if different methods are included on each declaration, otherwise you will see this error message :( Using latest TestNG 6.8.8. I was able to get this to work with @Test(priority=#) with the specific priority on each test method. See http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations.

My use case: crud tests for entities. Each Entity has its own test class with 4 methods (so I can test only a single entity CRUD in isolation), but I also want to run the overall suite (will fail due to integrity constraints and different generated ID keys unless they are run in exactly the right order).

Same question asked at [org.testng.TestNGException: No free nodes found in:[DynamicGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784768/org-testng-testngexception-no-free-nodes-found-indynamicgraph).